# Send HTTP request and read XML response

Tags: swift, xml

I'm trying to connect an app to my Trend Controller at home, but now I'm stuck on the following problem:

How can I send in Swift(4) the following request for example:
[HTTP request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QNPI.png)

and read the XML and extract the value in the XML response:
[XML Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlEVC.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) and [Fuzi](https://github.com/cezheng/Fuzi). Here is a minimal example of extracting a XML value from a HTTP request. For a specific solution please have a look at the documentation.

```
Alamofire.request("https://example.com/request").responseString { response in
    var xml: XMLDocument?
    do {
        xml = try XMLDocument(string: response.value ?? "")
    } catch {
        return
    }
    guard xml != nil else {
        return
    }
    guard let value = xml!.firstChild(xpath: "/tag1/tag2")?.stringValue else {
        return
    }
    print value
}
```